# Why sequundus > secundus?

Tags: language-evolution, orthography, morphology, spelling

It seems quite clear that *secundus* comes from *sequundus*, a gerundive of *sequi*.
But why did *-quu-* become *-cu-*?
This change is not universal, since some Latin words do preserve *-quu-*, at least the end of a word (consider *equus* and *aequus* for example).
I suppose this sound or spelling change is behind the dative *cui* and genitive *cuius* of *quis*.
Is there a rule that could help me predict when a *-quu-* becomes *-cu-*?
Are there notable examples or exceptions I should be aware of?

Comment: The rule is qu (effectively kʷ) lost it labialization before u/o, so secundus is a regular development. Re: equus see the link from Allen

Comment: Interestingly enough, this was the continuation of a rule from PIE (the "boukólos rule"), which also remained productive for quite some time in Germanic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### *Secundus* is regular, *eqvus* isn't

There's a sound change called the "Boukólos Rule", which started back in Proto-Indo-European. When labiovelar consonants (like `/kʷ/` and `/gʷ/`) appeared next to `/w/` or `/u/`, they dissimilated and lost their labialization, becoming `/k/` and `/g/`. The rule is named after one of the first known examples, Greek *βουκόλος* "cowherd".

In Latin, a *u* `/u/` vowel continued to turn a preceding labiovelar *qv* `/kʷ/` into a plain velar *c* `/k/`. So *seqv-* + *-undus* became *secundus*, which was perfectly regular at the time.

The rule eventually ceased to be relevant in most Indo-European languages (for example Greek lost its labiovelars entirely). But in both Latin and Germanic, later sound changes created more `/u/` sounds. And the Boukólos Rule continued to apply to these.

The short *o* in the second-declension endings shifted to a *u* between Old and Classical Latin, giving the familiar endings *-us* and *-um*. And this new *u* transformed second-declension nouns ending with labiovelars. This also created the irregularity in the relative pronoun: *qvī qvae qvod*, but *cujus, cui* (originally **qvojos, *qvoi*).

But while the relative pronouns were fairly fossilized (hence the archaic endings), and the gerundive in *-undus* was falling out of use, the second-declension endings were still very common and productive. And the paradigm *ecus, eqvī, eqvō, ecum, eqvō, eqve* looked inconsistent and wrong.

So in writing, it became standard to write *qv* for a plain velar `/k/`, **only before the second declension endings *-us, -um***. [Allen's *Vox Latina*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=ecus%20equus&source=bl&ots=TxPwnk4zUY&sig=pM1w0pHT75ixsMSSsZZqWb_iQ5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicjuPL76PVAhUW52MKHQduA9Q4ChDoAQhBMAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) quotes Velius Longius (writing in the second century AD):

> Auribus qvidem sufficiebat ut *eqvus* per unum *u* scriberetur, ratio tamen duo exigit.
> *Indeed, to the ears it is fine to write **eqvus** with a single **u**, but the mind demands two.*

Despite this, forms like *ecus* are still found in inscriptions, indicating that the true pronunciation was still `/k/`.

Comment: The Latin change is similar to the boukolos rule but not quite the same: it's not limited to labiovelars, but includes deletion of other [w] before [u] , e.g. *parum* from *parvum*. Also, it doesn't operate when a labiovelar follows [u], as in *boukolos* itself.

Comment: @TKR Was *parvum* pronounced *parum*? I did not know that; I'll do more research and edit accordingly.

Comment: I meant the adverb *parum* "too little", which is etymologically the same as the neuter adjective *parvum*.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of the second half of 2017.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/79)