# GalliJa? Was "i" between consonant and vowel pronounced "ij"?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation

How was **consonant + i + vowel** pronounced in Classical Latin - for example, in the words [*Gallia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gallia) and [*diurnus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diurnus)?

I googled a bit and found videos sounding for me like [gallija], [gallia] and even [gallja], the first predominating. W. S. Allen's *Vox Latina—a Guide to the Pronunciation of Classical Latin* ([page 40](https://books.google.ru/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA40)) says in a footnote that

> The pronunciation *[in some other situation]* may in fact have been no different from that of words like *diurnus*, where the *i* would automatically induce a consonantal *i*-glide before another vowel,

but does not mention it in the main text. If [ij] is indeed correct, then why neither [Wiktionary pronunciation guide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_pronunciation#I_and_J) nor other online sources I found mention [j]?

Comment: Not really relevant to an answer, but I was trying to pronounce _Gallia_ without the "i-glide" as that source calls it, and I was having some issues! You almost need a glottal stop there to prevent the sounds from just meshing together in that way. That may just be my native accent, but it certainly wasted a minute of my time looking like an idiot saying _Gallia_ out loud over and over again!

Comment: Similar: [How was “VV” pronounced?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5201)