# Translation of "I am made from the dust of the stars"

Tags: grammar-choice, prefix

I am looking to have something embodied that says:

> "I am made from the dust of the stars"

The quote is for [a man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Peart), and I rather keep the to-be verb in the present tense (*I am*, not *I was*) if possible. I've been researching online the best way to translate it to latin, and I am torn between two options:

1. Factus sum ex pulvere stellarum
2. Ex stellarum pulvere factus sum

I am also unsure if either ***Ex*** or ***E*** should be used as a preposition in this case, as I know little to nothing about Latin grammar. Can a kind soul please advise? Thanks!

Comment: You'll find [this thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/why-ex-nihilo-instead-of-e-nihilo) helpful. Basically, the only difference between those two sentences is the word order. The first is more in line with English, the second is better Latin.

Comment: @cmw Thank you for that. Would you replace all U with V?

Comment: No, that's only a stylistic preference. See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/why-do-many-write-latin-words-with-both-letters-v-u/). I'd only do that if you were writing in caps.

Comment: Is *factus* the best choice for *made* here? I think it implies a creative/agentic act of *making*, whereas I naturally interpret the English as being about material composition.

Comment: @dbmag9 I think it is based on what you said. It is more poetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to put into an answer what I said in the comments, this is generally a fine translation. Some notes:

a) I'd go with [*ex*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/why-ex-nihilo-instead-of-e-nihilo), since it's more common, nor are you using a standard phrase with *e*.

b) Instead of *ex*, you could also do *de*. It's perfectly classical, but it will probably remind people of Genesis 2 (the second creation story in Genesis), where God made Adam *de limo terrae* ("from the mud of earth").

c) I would prefer the second order, as it feels more Latinate, while the former feels like it was composed with the English word order in mind.

d) *Factus sum* is actually not present tense, but perfect. However, things completed in the past can indicate a status for the present, so it really doesn't change anything at all. That said, it means more "[am/have been] [fashioned/constructed]." This would be different from "I am comprised of", as dbmag9 mentions in the comments. For that, you might use a genitive of quality instead. But as I don't think that's the direction you're going for, I would stick with *factus* (cf. *statua ex aere facta*, Cic. *Verr*. 2.2.21).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will likely have it all in caps, as follows: EX STELLARVM PVLVERE FACTVS SVM. Just out of curiosity, do you have any favourite typeet that resembles old Latin? I am aware that any roman alphabet font will do, just curious!

Comment: @pmdci In the case of all caps, then yes, V not U is standard. I don't have a font in particular, sorry. I think there is a graphic design site on StackExchange that might be able to help with that, though.