# When did equus regain its first U?

Tags: pronunciation, language-evolution

I learned from [this question about *sequundus* > *secundus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4901/79) that *-quus* was in fact pronounced as if it was *-cus*.
However, words like *equus* were not spelled as *ecus*, since most oblique cases would still have the original stem *equ-* since *qu>c* only occurred before a *u*.
That is, *equus* was pronounced *ecus* but was spelled *equus* by analogy.

I would assume that at some point the spelling *equus* caused the pronunciation to become *equus* instead of *ecus* again.
At least this is the case in the contemporary Finnish pronunciation.
I have no idea when this change happened, other than "somewhere between imperial Rome and present day Finland", but I suspect this *equus* pronunciation (as opposed to *ecus*) was not unusual in some form of medieval or later Latin.
Do we know when — if ever — this change took place?
When was *equus* pronounced as *equus* and no longer *ecus*?
Any examples or a *terminus ante/post quem* are most welcome; I don't expect anyone to be able to point a precise point in time.

Comment: Analogy of inflected forms like *equis* reinforces the second u at any time; is there good evidence that it was ever lost?

Comment: @jknappen The answer to the linked question argues that *equus* was pronounced as if it were *ecus* (as mentioned by a Roman, too), so the first U was lost by the classical era. The spelling was maintained by analogy to oblique cases, but pronunciation was not. I was surprised!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is, the answer for *eqvus* will be earlier than the answer for most other words. In the Classical period *eqvus* was a common, everyday word, but at some point in Vulgar Latin it was displaced by the Gaulish loan *caballus*. Once *eqvus* wasn't used in day-to-day speech, it would be easy for a spelling pronunciation to take over.

In general, though, I'd date these sorts of spelling pronunciations to **the European Renaissance**. That's the point where Latin somewhat stopped evolving naturally: Desiderius Erasmus and others realized that their Latin pronunciation had been heavily affected by Romance, and decided to "purify" it. Erasmus in particular wrote [a long treatise](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/De_recta_latini_graecique_sermonis_pronuntiatione_1643) on how the pronunciation of Greek and Latin had degraded, and listed ways to make it Latin again: distinguishing *ae* from *ē*, removing palatalization before *i*, and so on.

Before Erasmus, I wouldn't expect any Romance-speaker to go from the easier `/ku/` to the more difficult `/kwu/` (except through spelling pronunciation for an obscure word). But once there was a conscious attempt to imitate the gold standard of Cicero and Vergil—that is, to imitate specifically the *written* words of Cicero and Vergil—less natural but more prestigious pronunciations make complete sense.